# After() not reaching next iteration in splash window

Tags: python, tkinter, gif

I have a splash window in a tkinter application, which is a child class of `Toplevel`. My target is to show a GIF moving, thus I am trying with a recurrent `.after()` function to update a `Label`. My code for the Splash window is:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Splash(tk.Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
    
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    
        self.overrideredirect(True)
    
        self.parent = parent
            
        frames = [tk.PhotoImage(file="myfile.gif",format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(89)] #it has 89 frames

        def animate(ind, label):
        
            frame = frames[ind]
                                
            ind += 1
        
            if ind>88: #With this condition it will play gif infinitely
            
                ind = 0
                            
            label.configure(image=frame)
                    
            label.update()
                                            
            self.after(110, animate, ind, label)

        label = tk.ttk.Label(self)
    
        label.pack(expand=1)
    
        self.after(0, animate, 0, label)
    
        self.parent.overrideredirect(True)
    
        self.update()
    
        self.lift()
```

Now: I tried to also put a `print` function before the next `after` call, and  I could see that it reached that step. However, if I place a `print(str(ind))` at the beginning of the `animate` function, I see only the first index appearing.

How can I actually loop in a `Toplevel` window in the correct way?

**EDIT:**

To add context to this, I have the main class `App` where I do the following:

```
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle, ThemedTk
import GUI.splash as sp

class App:

    def __init__(self, ...):

        self.interface = ThemedTk()

        self.interface.iconify()

        splash = sp.Splash(self.interface)

        ...

        self.interface.after(3000, splash.destroy) #Thanks @CoolCloud

        self.interface.deiconify()

        self.interface.mainloop()
```

**EDIT 2:**

I have tried with a minimum reproducible example:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    class Splash(tk.Toplevel):

        def __init__(self, parent):
    
            tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
    
            self.overrideredirect(True)
    
            self.parent = parent
            
            frames = [tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/temp/splash.gif",format = 'gif -index %i' %(i)) for i in range(89)] #it has 89 frames

            def animate(ind, label):
        
                frame = frames[ind]
                                
                ind += 1
        
                if ind>88: #With this condition it will play gif infinitely
            
                    ind = 0
                            
                label.configure(image=frame)
                    
                label.update()
                                            
                self.after(110, animate, ind, label)

            label = tk.Label(self)
    
            label.pack(expand=1)
    
            self.after(0, animate, 0, label)
        
            self.update()
    
            self.lift()

    class App:

        def __init__(self):

            self.interface = tk.Tk()

            self.interface.iconify()

            splash = Splash(self.interface)

            self.interface.after(3000, splash.destroy)

            self.interface.deiconify()

            self.interface.mainloop()
        
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        App()
```

It looks like the actual problem is the **size** of my underlying window, or at least that's what I would think, since in my case I load multiple frames (one on top of the other one) and switch between them depending on an OptionMenu. Maybe this is too much, however it works much better than destroying and rebuilding everything.

Btw, **keeping my app heavy as it is**, is there a better way to produce a splash screen to load my interface **and** show a gif moving as in my minimal example? The gif can be downloaded here: https://images.app.goo.gl/Bpi6EvpJgodiQs2e7

Comment: You're only calling `.after()` again in the condition `ind>88` - but that's not true on the first animation step, so nothing further happens.

Comment: @jasonharper, sorry it is actually a problem of indentation here, in the code it is fine. Let me correct, thanks!

Comment: When I run the code, the full animation sequence works for me, though instead of an image I'm using a list of strings. A `print` statement at the top of `animate` is executed for every element in the loop.

Comment: @Bryan are you doing this in a `Toplevel` window as I did? I am supposing on the main `Tk()` it works, hope that is not the case. With a `print` function at the beginning of the loop, it is not working for me (as I said). I have retried to make sure, and it doesn't work...

Comment: Yes, I used the code you posted, with the few necessary changes to make it work (specifically, added missing import, creating a root window, instantiating `Splash`, etc)

Comment: @Bryan: thanks, I have put what I did in my `App` class, I hope this helps.

Comment: `self.interface.after(3000, splash.destroy())` will destroy the file immediately, get rid of the `()`, so `self.interface.after(3000, splash.destroy)` like this.

Comment: @CoolCloud thank you for your help! But still this didn't help much: the problem now is that it actually starts to move, but only after the first seconds. It loads the first image, stays for a bit, loads the second one, stays still for a bit (less than first time), then it works properly.

Comment: Please provide a _complete_ [mcve]. If we have to change, add, or delete any lines at all there's a chance we're not going to duplicate your problem. It also needs to be minimal, so remove ttkthemes unless it's critical to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I did it (the second part is the main app). Also, ttkthemes is necessary for that part indeed (it's a ThemedTk app with my custom theme applied to all the widgets, omitted for simplicity). Is it missing something for which it wouldn't work?

Comment: The question isn't whether ttkthemes is necessary for your complete program, the question is whether it's necessary for us to reproduce this problem. What it's missing is that it's syntactically incorrect. "..." is not valid python syntax. Plus, it would be best if it was all together and didn't require us to create multiple files in multiple directories.

Comment: Ok, I understand, the problem is that I think the fact that one class uses the other one in its code is crucial. But let me modify my code so that one can reproduce the thing.